# How to hide FloatingActionButton under keyboard and not textformfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

So I am trying to hide FloatingActionButton using `resizeToAvoidBottomInsert: false,` but it also hiding textformfield. Is there any way to just hide FloatingActionButton alone and not textformfield and textformfield should appear when the keyboard appears. If you have time please share some kt how to focus textformfield because every time it only focusing first textfield. Below I attaching the Screenshots and full code.
[image: textformfield hiding below keyboard][image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CardWithTextformfield(),
    );
  }
}

class CardWithTextformfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWithTextformfield({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWithTextformfieldState createState() => _CardWithTextformfieldState();
}

class _CardWithTextformfieldState extends State<CardWithTextformfield>  {


  var name =<TextEditingController>[];
  var id =<TextEditingController>[];
  


  var addCard =1;  
  bool cardOneVisibility=true;
  bool cardTwoVisibility=false;
  bool cardThreeVisibility=false;
  bool cardFourVisibility=false;
  bool cardFiveVisibility=false;
  bool cardSixVisibility=false;


  void incrementcard(){
    setState(() {
      
      if(addCard==0){   
        cardOneVisibility=true;
      }
      else if(addCard==1){ 
        cardOneVisibility=true;
        cardTwoVisibility=true;
      }
      else if(addCard==2){ 
        cardOneVisibility=true;
        cardTwoVisibility=true;
        cardThreeVisibility=true;
      }
      else if(addCard==3){  
        cardOneVisibility=true;
        cardTwoVisibility=true;
        cardThreeVisibility=true;
        cardFourVisibility=true;
      }
      else if(addCard==4){  
        cardOneVisibility=true;
        cardTwoVisibility=true;
        cardThreeVisibility=true;
        cardFourVisibility=true;
        cardFiveVisibility=true;
      }
      else if(addCard==5){  
        cardOneVisibility=true;
        cardTwoVisibility=true;
        cardThreeVisibility=true;
        cardFourVisibility=true;
        cardFiveVisibility=true;
        cardSixVisibility=true;
      }
      addCard++;

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Card with TextformField'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addCard>=6 ? null : incrementcard, 
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Container(

        child:SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Visibility(visible: cardOneVisibility,child: cardslist(0)),
              Visibility(visible: cardTwoVisibility,child: cardslist(1)),
              Visibility(visible: cardThreeVisibility,child: cardslist(2)),
              Visibility(visible: cardFourVisibility,child: cardslist(3)),
              Visibility(visible: cardFiveVisibility,child: cardslist(4)),
              Visibility(visible: cardSixVisibility,child: cardslist(5)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget cardslist(int index){
    if(name.length <= index){
      name.add(TextEditingController());
      id.add(TextEditingController());
    }
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text('Team Name: ')),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: name[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Name'),
                ),),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('Team Id: '),),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: id[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Id'),
                ),),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color:Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('IT'),),
                  ),
                 
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('DEV'),),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('TEST'),),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('HR'),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @JahidulIslam I tried but FAB is disappeared only after all cards reached the maximum number, but the problem is when I tried to give input in the 4th or 5th card textformfield is hiding below the FAB .screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNSlp.png

Comment: but in my machine it works fine

Comment: ohh, is there any way

Comment: updated my answer please check

Comment: I tried it but not working

Comment: please check it again i hope this time it works for you

Comment: Hey @JahidulIslam sorry but it is not working

Comment: i got the issue and updated again please check one more time

Answer (score 1):

To hide the FloatingActionButton when opening the keyboard, I use this:

```
floatingActionButton: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? null : FloatingActionButton(
  // FloatingActionButton code
)
```

As written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751912/15564482) answer, MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom detects when the keyboard is opened or not.

Using MediaQuery, the screen will be rebuilt automatically when that value changes, so when the keyboard is closed, the floatingActionButton is rendered, instead, when user opens the keyboard, the floatingActionButton  will be null.

Answer (score 0):

please check. remove `resizeToAvoidBottomInsert: false,` and controll floating button based on addCard size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CardWithTextformfield(),
    );
  }
}

class CardWithTextformfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWithTextformfield({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWithTextformfieldState createState() => _CardWithTextformfieldState();
}

class _CardWithTextformfieldState extends State<CardWithTextformfield> {
  List<TextEditingController> name = <TextEditingController>[];
  List<TextEditingController> id = <TextEditingController>[];

  var addCard = 1;
  bool cardOneVisibility = true;
  bool cardTwoVisibility = false;
  bool cardThreeVisibility = false;
  bool cardFourVisibility = false;
  bool cardFiveVisibility = false;
  bool cardSixVisibility = false;

  bool showFab = false;

  void incrementcard() {
    setState(() {
      if (addCard == 0) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
      } else if (addCard == 1) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
        cardTwoVisibility = true;
      } else if (addCard == 2) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
        cardTwoVisibility = true;
        cardThreeVisibility = true;
      } else if (addCard == 3) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
        cardTwoVisibility = true;
        cardThreeVisibility = true;
        cardFourVisibility = true;
      } else if (addCard == 4) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
        cardTwoVisibility = true;
        cardThreeVisibility = true;
        cardFourVisibility = true;
        cardFiveVisibility = true;
      } else if (addCard == 5) {
        cardOneVisibility = true;
        cardTwoVisibility = true;
        cardThreeVisibility = true;
        cardFourVisibility = true;
        cardFiveVisibility = true;
        cardSixVisibility = true;
      }
      addCard++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Card with TextformField'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: !keyboardIsOpen,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: addCard >= 6 ? null : incrementcard,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Visibility(visible: cardOneVisibility, child: cardslist(0)),
          Visibility(visible: cardTwoVisibility, child: cardslist(1)),
          Visibility(visible: cardThreeVisibility, child: cardslist(2)),
          Visibility(visible: cardFourVisibility, child: cardslist(3)),
          Visibility(visible: cardFiveVisibility, child: cardslist(4)),
          Visibility(visible: cardSixVisibility, child: cardslist(5)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cardslist(int index) {
    if (name.length <= index) {
      name.add(TextEditingController(text: ""));
      id.add(TextEditingController(text: ""));
    }
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Team Name: ')),
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: name[index],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Name'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text('Team Id: '),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: id[index],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Id'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('IT'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('DEV'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('TEST'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('HR'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```